# Chrome extension error while testing project on Travis CI

Tags: protractor, travis-ci

We have very recently started receiving the below error in our open source project while running protractor tests on Travis CI. This error is caused only on Travis CI and not reproduced locally. The error message is:

'chrome-extension://invalid/ - Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED'

Is this an issue on the chrome side of things? Because it doesn't seem to be on ours.

Comment: I think it is more of a Travis CI issue. Do you have a copy of your `.travis.yml` ?